# Windows 8 reboot causes an infinite loop

Tags: windows-8, reboot, infinite-loop

I have installed Windows 8 Professional 64-bit in a VHD that dual boots with Windows 7. The VHD is dynamically expanding with a 128 GB capacity.

When windows 8 reboots, it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop and will say "Restarting" while the five dots circle around for hours and hours. When I use the power button to force it to turn off, it sometimes says, "Your PC ran into a problem". This error message tells me absolutely nothing that I don't already know. What happened to useful error messages?

If I use the command line `shutdown /r /f /t 0` it actually reboots. Is there a way to set the default arguments?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using shutdown /f? A forced shutdown could cause problems with some properly functioning programs as well.

Comment: The problem occurs on reboot every time the `/f` switch is not used, but it never occurs if the `/f` switch is used. `shutdown /s` works correctly without the `/f` switch. Only reboots are affected.

Comment: @Jay I have been using Windows 8 Pro for about 2 weeks and have not had any problems with programs not working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the best solution is not to use VHD boot. After reinstalling Windows 8 directly in a [partition](https://superuser.com/questions/520801/only-three-primary-partitions) on my hard drive, the problem has been resolved.

While VHD boot is a cool feature, unfortunately it seems that it is not yet ready for serious use.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `.bat` file called `shutdown2` containing the following

```
shutdown /r /f /t 0
```

Put it in a folder of your choice, I.E. `C:\scripts` and add that location to your Path variable. Easiest way to do this is

1. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
2. Type `system environment variables`
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Environment Variables
5. Under System variables select Path and click Edit
6. Scroll to the end and add `; C:\scripts`. The semicolon is necessary because it separates it from the previous entry

Now you can run `shutdown2` just like any other command, either in command prompt or through <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: I already have a batch file called `reboot.bat` with those arguments. I was hoping to set the default arguments in the registry so that when programs (e.g. Windows Update) decide I need to reboot, the machine does not end up stuck in an infinite loop in case I forget to cancel the reboot and enter the command manually.

Comment: You could try renaming `shutdown.exe` in `C:\Windows\system32` to `shutdown2.exe` and placing your new file in there. The only caveat is that some programs might expect it to be a `.exe` file instead of a `.bat` and some programs won't even use `shutdown.exe`. There are many ways to shutdown/restart a computer.